# make opencv on windows,get a error

Tags: c++, opencv, makefile, mingw-w64

I using cmake and **mingw-w64** to make **opencv** on **windows 10**,however,i get a error when make it on 97%.
there are error report:

```
[ 96%] Built target opencv_videostab
[ 97%] Building CXX object modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/__/src2/cv2.cpp.obj
In file included from C:/PROGRA~1/Python36/include/Python.h:8:0,
                 from D:\Program Files (x86)\OpenCv_3.2.0\opencv\sources\modules\python\src2\cv2.cpp:6:
C:/PROGRA~1/Python36/include/pyconfig.h:379:5: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]
 #if _MSC_VER >= 1800
     ^~~~~~~~
In file included from D:/Program Files (x86)/MinGw_64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/include/c++/math.h:                                                                                                36:0,
                 from C:/PROGRA~1/Python36/include/pyport.h:194,
                 from C:/PROGRA~1/Python36/include/Python.h:50,
                 from D:\Program Files (x86)\OpenCv_3.2.0\opencv\sources\modules\python\src2\cv2.cpp:6:
D:/Program Files (x86)/MinGw_64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/include/c++/cmath:42:10: fatal error: D:/                                                                                                Program Files (x86)/MinGw_64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/include/c++/bits/cpp_type_traits.h>: Invalid                                                                                                 argument
 #include <bits/cpp_type_traits.h>s
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
mingw32-make[2]: ***[modules\python3\CMakeFiles\opencv_python3.dir\build.make:180: modules/python3/CMakeFiles/ope                                                                                                ncv_python3.dir/__/src2/cv2.cpp.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:6794: modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:160: all] Error 2
```

What can i do to slove it?

update:
i had sloved it,it's a bug fot mingww64,the error erport

```
 :cmath:42:10: fatal error: D:/ Program Files (x86)/MinGw_64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/include/c++/bits/cpp_type_traits.h>: Invalid argument #include <bits/cpp_type_traits.h>s
```

said having a error to head file,so i just delete the 's' after include statement,that is `include <bits/cpp_type_traits.h>`

Comment: looks like a problem with python module, do you need it? if not, try disabling it, otherwise mingw may require python to be installed/configured?

Comment: i had sloved it,it's a bug fot mingww64,the error erport ##:cmath:42:10: fatal error: D:/                                                                                                Program Files (x86)/MinGw_64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/include/c++/bits/cpp_type_traits.h>: Invalid                                                                                                 argument
 #include <bits/cpp_type_traits.h>s##said having  a error to head file,so i just remove the 's' after include  statement,that is ##include <bits/cpp_type_traits.h>##

Comment: You might want to post this as an answer to the question so that it may help others in the future